# unable to connect service plan to vnet

Tags: azure

I am trying to configure app services to use a virtual network and prevent them from being directly publicly accessible.  When i try to connect them to a vnet, my vnet is grayed out with a message "this virtual network has no gateway" i have setup a subnet gateway on the vnet still get the message.  How do i link these services to my vnet?

[image: app service vnet config]

[image: vnetsubnets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you just add the named `GatewaySubnet` subnet in your current virtual network. It's not enough. You need to create a virtual network gateway resource first then set up a VPN gateway in your virtual network. For example, you could [configure a Point-to-Site VPN connection to a VNet using native Azure certificate authentication via Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal)

**VNet**

[image]

**Virtual network gateway with VPN type**

[image]

Another option is to use [Regional VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). In this case, you do not need a gateway in that VNet. Go to the Networking UI in the portal. If your app is able to use the new feature, then you will see an option to **Add VNet (preview)**.

Comment: Add VNet (preview) is not available.  i have tried creating a new service plan app service but still unable to get the preview option.

Comment: `Your App Service plan must be a Standard, Premium, or Premium V2 plan. The new capability is available only from newer Azure App Service scale units. The VNet Integration UI in the portal will tell you if your app can use the new feature. Production workloads are not supported on the new feature while it’s in preview.` view [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-app-service-vnet-integration-feature/) for more details.

Comment: After following that guide i got the error in the screenshots above "this network has no gateway"

Comment: Do you have created a virtual network gateway based on the VPN type? and set the `address pool` of `point to site configuration`? please check my updated screenshots.

Comment: @Stephen I was having a similar issue regarding the regional vnet integration. It worked once I set the app service plan to P1V2. Their documentation lists it as a limitation, short version being that you use Azure App Service scale units that support PremiumV2 App Service plans.